# Creating menu item with description

Tags: html, css, menu

Today I tried something unique, so I decided to code my template.

You know some menus have a title and a description?

EXAMPLE:

Homepage
Our main page

Twitter
Follow us!

Thats how the menu should look like:

http://gyazo.com/360b81db32cf61922e9ff8f55274d779

Okay I tried adding a description simply by using 
 in a li item and it didnt work at all!

```
<div class="header">
     <div class="container">
           <div id="logo"><a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png"/></a></div>
                <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                <li>Home<br /> Main Page</li>
                <li>Home<br /> Main Page</li>
                <li>Home<br /> Main Page</li>
                <li>Home<br /> Main Page</li>
                <li>Home<br /> Main Page</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

That's the CSS I used:

```
.header {
background: #6b6353 url("../img/header.png");
width: 100%;
height: 112px;
}

#logo {
float: left;
margin-top:22px;
}

.subheader {
background: #deac12 url("../img/subheader.png");
width: 100%;
height: 36px;
}

.menu ul li{
display: inline;
}
```

Why doesn't it work even though it has inline & a break?

What happens with that code:

http://gyazo.com/a585ed4b408f3c6ed2583244ea4ff236

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `display: inline-block` for your li and for God's sake stop using `<br>` tags, use a `<span>` or a `<p>` instead.

Comment: @Jony you don't. That's the point, <br /> it's an obsolete tag, we don't use it any more. Instead you can use `<li>Home<span>Main Page</span></li>` It's easier this way to style your entire menu.

Comment: Thanks I used span class & display: block for the description and worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu ul li{
    float: left;    
}​
```

will solve your problem. You get the newlines, but the 2nd `li` starts immediately after the 2nd newline (the 1st line of the 2nd li will start next to the 2nd line of the 1st li), so this is something like

```
[Home
Main Page][Home
Main Page][Home
Main Page]...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
.menu ul li{
list-style: none;
float: left;
}
```

Removing `display: inline;` will make the list styling visible, that's why `list-style: none;`, and the `float: left;` will make all `<li>` to be on the same line.